# Using Frank/Cucumber for XCode Automation Testing

Tags: cucumber, xcode4.3, frank, cucumber-junit

I am trying to explore different ways of possibly doing Automation testing for my XCode apps and came across Frank/Cucumber but I am just really confused about how it all works. What steps does Cucumber take in actually starting the test? You have your feature files(*.feature files) which seems to favor an english style of writing of sorts then you have have your definitions which are scripts that I assume link up with each of the features? I have never done ruby programming before so that is probably the source of most of my confusion.

Can anyone explain exactly how it works? Is it useful in an agile environment where you might have changes after a one week sprint? My thought was that if you have all these features and all these scripts, pretty soon it could become a headache to maintain but thats just me thinking about the long term.

Any help and thoughts would be appreciative. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Frank/Cucumber is a very useful tool to test the x code and is very useful in agile environment.

All you need to is install the gem and have a frankified version of the app.

Then go ahead with the set up of symbiote-it is used to inspect the UI of the app.

Then create a feature file against your x code directory, it is written in simple English and tells the steps of testing an element.

Then create a step definiton file and write the ruby code for the steps defined in feature file.

Go ahead and run it from the terminal and see your tests getting passed.